# making command that shows number of used application commands. pycord

Tags: python, discord, pycord

I want to make a command, that shows the number of used slash commands.
I've tried making this with using json file, but it was bad idea.
So the code:

```
# in events.py
count = 0
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_application_command(self, context):
        global count
        count = count + 1
        with open('total_commands.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(count, f)

# in general.py
json_file = 'total_commands.json'
with open(json_file) as json_data:
    cmds = json.load(json_data)

@discord.slash_command(
        name="total_commands",
        description="Get number of used commands"
    )
async def total_commands(self, ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Number of used commands", description=cmds, color=0x9C84EF)
    await ctx.respond(embed=embed)
```

problem of this code is that count variable is reseting after using /total_commands

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're only loading `total_commands.json` once. Therefore, `cmds` is always going to be that first value - regardless of whether it's updated through `on_application_command`. You need to be reading the file within the command:

```py
@discord.slash_command(
    name="total_commands",
    description="Get number of used commands"
)
async def total_commands(self, ctx):
    json_file = 'total_commands.json'
    with open(json_file) as json_data:
        cmds = json.load(json_data)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Number of used commands", description=cmds, color=0x9C84EF)
    await ctx.respond(embed=embed)
```